# Can't install mint-meta-cinnamon on LinuxMint Cinnamon-19

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, linux-mint, cinnamon

When I ran `sudo apt-get install mint-meta-cinnamon`,

I got these errors :

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that **you have
>   requested an impossible situation** or if you are **using the unstable
>   distribution** that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    `mint-meta-cinnamon` : Depends: `cinnamon-screensaver-x-plugin` but it is not going to be installed
>   **E: Unable to correct problems**, you have held broken packages.

*I tried so hard and I even tried to install them one by one but it didn't work.*
Can someone help please?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install cinnamon-screensaver-x-plugin` first?

Comment: Yeah, then I got this error:


`Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cinnamon-screensaver-x-plugin : Depends: cinnamon-screensaver (>= 3.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Not sure what's happening there. Sometimes I find I can get a better grasp on things using the gui `synaptic`.

Comment: ... try deleting here and reposting to https://askubuntu.com (as you have included an `ubuntu` tag). Good luck.